# Get Collections in Java from MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a local MongoDB instance running via shell on windows 10. 
University provided a Java Project for us to learn about queries.

Now, I have a database ("imdb") and want to get two collections from it ("movies","tweets").

The problem is, one the one hand

```
List<String> test = mongo.getDatabaseNames();
System.out.println(test); //prints [admin,config,imdb,local]
...
db = mongo.getDB("imdb");
System.out.println(db.getCollectionNames()); //prints []
```

There seem to be no collections on imdb but

```
db.createCollection("movies", new BasicDBObject());
```

Returns a com.mongodb.CommandFailureException, stating that a collection 'imdb.movies' already exists.

So how do I ensure that Java actually "loads" the Collections?
For Clarification: My goal is to have

```
System.out.println(db.getCollectionNames());
```

to print [movies,tweets] instead of []

Comment: The code trying to do an insert that is why you get already exists error, this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659504/find-all-objects-in-collection-java-mongodb) might help, just comment out the line db.createCollection("movies", new BasicDBObject()); your error will go away

Comment: I don't need the Error to go away, createCollection was just do check if movies "truely" doesnt exist in "imdb".

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

        for (String s : colls) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

ref: [code examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.mongodb.DB&method=getCollectionNames)

Comment: I think there is little difference in printing every String of a Set or the Set in whole.

Comment: But if you try it you can see if db.getCollectionNames() is returning anything.

Comment: Both should check if it returns anything. Anyhow, your suggestion doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Which version of mongodb shell you're using

If it's before 3.0, it will return no data for `db.getCollectionNames()` command

ref: [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/#considerations)

Comment: According to the zip file provided by university its Version 3.6

Comment: And [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#compatibility-drivers-wired-tiger) said it's also apply if you're using `WiredTiger storage engine`. Can you check if it's the case.

Comment: Not quiet sure how to check that, but running "show collections" in another shell returns both collections "movies","tweets". Therefore the java equivalent should work too!?

Comment: Can you try this command `db.serverStatus().storageEngine` in the mongo shell

Comment: Name = wiredTiger, supportscommittedreads = true, readonly = false, persisten = true
So it seems like it does use wiredTiger storage. But show collections works nontheless on the shell

Comment: No, and I'm not sure if that jeopardizes the code provided by university

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.0 you should use MongoDatabase.listCollectionNames() method.
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/#get-a-list-of-collections

```
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(dbName);
MongoIterable<String> names = db.listCollectionNames();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
//If you don't need connection's configures. i.e. your mongo is in you localhost at 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoClient cliente = new MongoClient(); //to connect into a mongo DB

MongoDatabase mongoDb = client.getDatabase("imdb");  //get database

MongoCollection<Document> robosCollection = mongoDb.getCollection("movies"); //get the name of the collection that you want

MongoCursor<Document> cursor =  robosCollection.find().cursor();//Mongo Cursor interface implementing the iterator protocol

    cursor.forEachRemaining(System.out::println); //print all documents in Collection using method reference
```